# Basecamp and OAuth

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, basecamp

I`m working on Android client for new Basecamp.

I registered my app at [integrate.37signals.com](http://integrate.37signals.com)  and set redirect URI to `newbcamp://success`

Now I`m getting such error:

```
Provided redirect_uri is not approved
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Generally in OAuth, the URL you provided at the time of registering your app with 37signals is the same URL you need to provide in your request

Comment: I know it. It looks, that problem is in schema - but i did not found, any information about this restriction

Comment: I was getting the same problem, but then looking [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#formingtheurl) in the second table, it says: "The value of this parameter must exactly match one of the values registered in the APIs Console". I know its not basecamp, but OAuth is pretty much the same everywhere.

Comment: Also, if the answer helps you, could you mark it as correct and/or upvote it?

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services) to handle **OAuth 2.0 Authentication**.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when doing authorization. I found there's slash at the end of my redirect_uri http://testapp.com/. It works after removing the last slash(http://testapp.com).

I think Basecamp should cover this kind of flaw because http://testapp.com/ is equivalent to http://testapp.com.